# function concept

Tags: c++

```
void execute(int &x,int y=100)
{
 x=x+y;
 cout<<x<<endl;
}
void main()
{
 int a=5,b=6;
 execute(b);
}
```

will the following program work in spite of not assigning a default value to the x(formal parameters in the function prototype).

Comment: I think your example got cut up in the posting process.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will work. By not assigning the default value to `x` you are forcing the caller to pass a value as the parameter. When you do `execute(b)` in main you are binding the reference `x` with actual parameter 'b' and since you have not passed any value to variable 'y' the default value will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there's no such thing as "function prototype" in C++. "Prototype" is a term from C parlance, which has no meaningful application in C++. What you have here is a function declaration, which also happens to be a function definition.

Secondly, it appears you are asking whether it is required to specify default arguments for all function arguments in C++, right? If so, the answer is no, there's no requirement to specify default arguments for all function arguments.

Thirdly, it is supposed to be `int main`, not `void main`.

Comment: The C++ standard (§ 3.3.3) defines "function prototype scope", a scope that "terminates at the end of the nearest enclosing function declarator."  I'd call that a "meaningful application."  There are other references beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

You run `execute(b)`, meaning that `execute` will run `b = b + 100` (`y` is 100 since you didn't pass it in, and it got the default value), print out 106 and `b` will be modified back in `main`, since it's taken by reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused as to how a function works. You're passing the value for x into it (well, a reference to an `int` not the actual value) so ... yes, that works.

By providing a default value for y ( `int y=100` ) you're making it so the function can be called without passing the second argument to it. If called with a single argument, y will be assigned the value 100.

```
int a=5,b=6;
execute(b);
```

Once inside execute(), the initial value of x is 6, and y is 100.